# How can I stop setInterval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to clear setInterval with calling clearInterval.
however, i call setInterval function inside function.
So I'd like to trigger the parameter in the setInterval by clearInterval,
But i do not know how to get reach this thing.
And what i say is confusing so I just want to show u the code :

```js
function getAPI() {
    const polling = () => {
      if (convert !== undefined) {
        axios
          .post("/realtime", {
            GET_API_URL: convert.GET_API_URL,
            Headers1_key: convert.Headers1_key,
            Headers1_Value: convert.Headers1_Value,
            Headers2_key: convert.Headers2_key,
            Headers2_Value: convert.Headers2_Value,
            Headers3_key: convert.Headers3_key,
            Headers3_Value: convert.Headers3_Value,
          })
          .then(response => {
            setRandom(response.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      } else {
        alert("try again.");
      }
    };
    setInterval(polling, convert.API_Read_Speed);
  }

  const init = () => {
    clearInterval(polling);  // i want to call polling and i want to stop the axios posting
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to your comment seems like you need to stop the polling in react.
you can use the `useRef` hook to keep the reference of the interval and clear it whenever you like.

```
 useEffect(() => {
  interval.current = setInterval(() => {
    ...
  }, ms)

 }, [input]);

 const closeConnection = () => {
  clearInterval(interval.current);

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store `setInterval` inside a variable and access it like that.
Example:

```js
let interval;

function foo() {
   interval = setInterval(() => {
      ...
   }, ms)
}

function bar() {
   clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, is it same in react ??

Comment: It does. example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-dan-sem9u?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You can open the console below and interact with the buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much !! why does my code not work  with this solution

Comment: Not exactly sure but you can try [Omid's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923472/omid) answer. Perhaps using refs for this will in-fact work for you.

Comment: It won't work without a ref because on rerender the variable is redeclared and the reference lost.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the inaccuracy. It is in-fact different in React when you take into account the re-rendering of components. My example is a simple one that assumes the component doesn't re-render.